# AJAX request Rails slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to send a JavaScript variable to my Rails controller through an AJAX request in order to use the variable to find the right instance of my model.

I can get my controller to print this variable, but I have not been able to save it anywhere such as a partial.

Here is my js.erb file:

```rb
  $(".single-item").on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'update_description',
    type: 'post',
    data: {slideNumber: $(".single-item").slick('slickCurrentSlide')},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
    }
  });
```

And my controller file:

```rb
def index
    @posts = Post.all
    if params[:slideNumber] == nil
        @slideNumber ||= 0
    else
    @slideNumber = params[:slideNumber]
    end

    puts @slideNumber
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {}
        format.js {}
    end
end
```

This puts `@slideNumber` in the controller correctly and prints the variable coming from JavaScript to console, however I am not able to pass it to a partial or to reuse it as a response from the JavaScript file. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried `respond_with @slideNumber`?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your reply. I tried replacing my `respond_to` block with a  `respond_with(@slideNumber)` but I'm still missing something because I don't get this variable

Comment: I get this error in console: POST http://localhost:3000/update_description 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: And this error in console: 
NoMethodError (undefined method `@slideNumber_url' for #<PostsController:0x007f78e441fc08>):

Comment: will that `index` method be only called by ajax? If not I would use a separate method

Comment: on second thought; your ajax has `url: 'update_description'`, so unless you are routing to `index` your method will never be called by ajax.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the server log, maybe you'll see that Rails is responding with the html content. Try adding .js to ajax request url so that Rails knows it should respond with js. For example:

```
var update_description = <%= "#{update_description_path}.js" %>
```